# Duplicate tables with the same name in SQL

Tags: sql, h2

If I wanted to create two or more duplicates of a table(lets say tableName), and store them in the **same database** without changing the original name... How would I go about doing that? Are there any features or commands I should look into?

Would I be able to do this all in one line?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The database concept may differ.)

Comment: You can't, the table names must be unique. Or they must be stored in seperate databases or have different schemas.

Comment: You can put them in different *schemas*.

Comment: @jarlh I'm using H2